# parsing date with "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" pattern

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am facing weird behavior with "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" date parsing pattern.
below is my code.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(parseDate("2018-08-16 11:00:00"));
        System.out.println(parseDate("2018-08-16 12:00:00"));
        System.out.println(parseDate("2018-08-16 13:00:00"));
    }

    public static Date parseDate(String date) throws Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        return sdf.parse(date);
    }
```

and I am getting following output

> Thu Aug 16 11:00:00 UTC 2018
>
> Thu Aug 16 00:00:00 UTC 2018
>
> Thu Aug 16 13:00:00 UTC 2018

I don't understand the second output why for "2018-08-16 12:00:00" its saying Thu Aug 16 00:00:00 UTC 2018 instead of Thu Aug 16 12:00:00 UTC 2018.

looking at the docs for date parsing pattern from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). It says

> h -> Hour in am/pm (1-12)

can someone please explain this? 
Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Without the `am`/`pm` value, what is `12`? I'd also suggest that you should be using the new date/time introduced in Java 8

Comment: try introducing am/pm

Comment: Or change your formatter to use `H` instead

Comment: Also, if you use the `SimpleDateFormat` (and the same format) to `format` the result, it will print `2018-08-16 12:00:00` :/ - Remember, `Date#toString` has it's own internal mechanism for formatting it's representation

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: As Ole V.V. commented, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have change bellow line

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

to

```
DateFormat writeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Hours date format like below,

```
kk :- Hours in 1-24 format
hh :- hours in 1-12 format
KK :- hours in 0-11 format
HH :- hours in 0-23 format
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(parseDate("2018-08-16 11:00:00 AM"));
    System.out.println(parseDate("2018-08-16 12:00:00 PM"));
    System.out.println(parseDate("2018-08-16 13:00:00 AM"));
}

public static Date parseDate(String date) throws Exception {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
    return sdf.parse(date);
}
```

**Output**

`Thu Aug 16 11:00:00 IST 2018
 Thu Aug 16 12:00:00 IST 2018
 Thu Aug 16 13:00:00 IST 2018`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `H` instead `hh` for `Hour in day (0-23)` :

### TestP:

```
public class TestP{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(parseDate("2018-08-16 11:00:00"));
        System.out.println(parseDate("2018-08-16 12:00:00"));
        System.out.println(parseDate("2018-08-16 13:00:00"));
        System.out.println(parseDate("2018-08-16 23:00:00"));
    }

    public static Date parseDate(String date) throws Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss");
        return sdf.parse(date);
    }
}
```

### Output:

```
Thu Aug 16 11:00:00 CLST 2018
Thu Aug 16 12:00:00 CLST 2018
Thu Aug 16 13:00:00 CLST 2018
Thu Aug 16 23:00:00 CLST 2018
```

Docs: [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: `AddRotatedAnnotation`??

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).